# index file automatically downloaded codeigniter installation

Tags: codeigniter, installation

When I trying to install a CodeIgniter project to a remote sever the index file in install folder automatically downloaded.. but there was no problem in local server. I can not solve the problem.. Please help me.. Please

Comment: its not clear what you are asking. write it out step by step so we understand your issue.

Comment: please goto the mcques.com/newmcques/

Comment: Nothing but a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your http server(apache/apache2/ngnix), i.e is not set up correctly, that's why instead of executing php file on the server it will get downloaded.